# How to display unique items and the amount of occurances from an array of objects in Vuejs/JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, array.prototype.map

I'm working on an inventory app with Vuejs for this project, but my problem is specifically a JS related one.
In my data I have the user data which is the logged userData which is taken from a form and then the static categories and locations which you can choose from below that.

I am trying to pull out the unique categories and how many times the appear in a new array of objects that would look like :

```
[{title: 'Books', amount: 3 }, {title: 'Recods', amount: 1 }, ...]
```

I believe what I have is a scope issue.

Data

```
userData: {
        items: [
          {
            itemName: 'test book',
            category: 'Books',
            location: 'Kitchen',
          },
          {
            itemName: 'test book 2',
            category: 'Books',
            location: 'Garage',
          },
          {
            itemName: 'test book 3',
            category: 'Books',
            location: 'Basement',
          },
          {
            itemName: 'test record',
            category: 'Records',
            location: 'Basement',
          },
          {
            itemName: 'test furniture',
            category: 'Furniture',
            location: 'Garage',
          },
        ],
        categories: ['Books', 'Movies', 'Records', 'Furniture'],
        locations: ['Basement', 'Garage', 'Kitchen'],
      },
```

I'm trying to get this to work like I have here with 'Books', but for all categories.
This is what I have displaying with the code below. It reads 'Items: 3' because I have 3 Books in my userData, but I need it to display the amount for each unique category.
I cannot figure out what to place in the code below
`filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.category === 'Books').length`

[image]

method/function

```
   convertedCategories() {
      const items = this.userData.items
      const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.category === 'Books').length

      function getItemCountOfCategory(categoryName) {
        return filteredItems
      }
      function convertCategoriesIntoCards(categories) {
        return categories.map((el) => {
          return {
            title: el,
            amount: getItemCountOfCategory(el),
          }
        })
      }
      return convertCategoriesIntoCards(this.userData.categories)
    },
```

I apologize if I haven't broken this down clear enough; it's still very hard for me to extract a particular line that pertains to the question out of so much code.

If anything is unclear, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
   convertedCategories() {
      const items = this.userData.items
      function getItemCountOfCategory(categoryName) {
        return items.filter((item) => item.category === categoryName).length
      }
      function convertCategoriesIntoCards(categories) {
        return categories.map((el) => {
          return {
            title: el,
            amount: getItemCountOfCategory(el),
          }
        })
      }
      return convertCategoriesIntoCards(this.userData.categories)
    },
```

Comment: Wow. This did work! Thank you!

So it was just moving the filteredItems variable I made into the function itself and then having the argument in place of the 'Books' value I had written above?
I'm glad I wasn't totally off there, but I wonder what made me think that defining the variable outside of the function was the right call... 

Anyway, thank you for the fast and concise response! I wasn't sure I properly asked the question.